# iphone & remote control tripod & stellarium

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing

I am curious if anyone has success using one of those (relatively) inexpensive remote controlled (motored) tripods designed for iphones, and astrophotography.

These little iphone tripods and motorized mounts are increasingly available and affordable. Seems like with the right kind of hardware and software interface, it might be possible to use stellarium or similar product to do some time lapse or other kinds of photography, especially if a feedback loop for object tracking is incorporated into the system.

This idea have any legs?

Comment: What "(relatively) inexpensive remote controlled (motored) tripods designed for iphones"? It would be great if you could add links to a few examples. That way one can see their specifications and get an idea how well they might work and/or what kind of control they do or don't need. I'm also thinking that Photography SE is a better place for this question.

Comment: See for example answers to [Milky Way with a cell phone, how is this possible?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112389/50110) which in addition to a motorized mount point out that you should be taking a series of shorter exposures and then stack them offline, for which there are several programs available some of which probably allow you to reduce noise in the process as well. You could also just stack them in Python with a bit of math. Shorter exposures avoid saturation and it's associated sensor artifacts, but for really dim stuff only, with a phone, I don't know if it beats long exposure.